# How to have two different types of navigation bar one fixed and one static with different menu items?

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can we have fixed navigation bar having same behaviour like this on website https://ooomf.com/ and also with two different type of menu items.

For example on the website above they have stories, how it works , blog and login at the top menu and when you scroll down in fixed menu "login" gets replaced with "start your project" button.

How do we accomplish that using css/jquery in bootstrap 3 ?

Help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with 2 navbars. The `affix` component is used to pin the 2nd navbar to the top once the user has scrolled past the top header. You can use CSS `z-index` to position the 2nd navbar over the first...

### http://www.bootply.com/118680

```
#topNav {
    z-index:-1;
}

#nav {
  width: 100%;
  position:static;
  top:-32px;
}

#nav.affix {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   z-index:10;
   -webkit-transition: all .6s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called a sticky navigation bar. Now you can find many variations of this but here is a great tutorial for a simple one.

**[Tutorial](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-sticky-position/)**

Answer (score 0):

You simply apply in bootstrap with **afix**

```
$('#navbar').affix({
  offset: {
    top: 50
  }
});
```

**Update**
Via data attributes
To easily add affix behavior to any element, just add data-spy="affix" to the element you want to spy on. Use offsets to define when to toggle the pinning of an element.

```
<div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="60">
  ...
</div>
```

You can set up on `data-offset-top="200"` when you need to show. here is the example

DEMO **http://jsfiddle.net/6P5sF/56/**

Reference: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Comment: That's kool. But do you see how both top menu and the sticky menu items are different. How do we accomplish that with affix ? And that sticky menu only appears when you scroll down after first panel.